# Export test Cases from MTM (Microsoft Test Manager)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, test-suite, mtm, test-plan

I'm trying to export my test cases from Microsoft Test Manager 2013 and i tried various tools but none is working.
I'm getting 2 different errors:
1) Must install microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client version 11.0.0.0 in the GAC
2) Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. Application has encountered Fatal Error. Please contact your System Administrator.

In case 2, i'm capable of connecting to the TFS. I get the error once i try to connect to the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that you're using some code to do this? Can you please show your code?

Comment: I'm not actually. There are tools that would connect to your TFS and projects. I've actually used the same tool on my previous machine that IT just changed for me...

Comment: Could you then tell us which tools you're using?

Comment: Sure.

https://tfstestcaseexporttoexcel.codeplex.com/                            

http://exporttfs2excel.codeplex.com/releases/view/70526